# How to change position of image of UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uibutton

I'm trying to bring up the image of my UIButton of a few pixels, does anyone knows how to do it? I tried with ContentEdgeInset but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So what you have tried and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: as according to your question, you will achieve it on UIButton ImageInsests (Left/Right/top/Bottom) in storyboard

Comment: I currently use `securityButton.titleEdgeInsets.top = 50 securityButton.imageEdgeInsets.bottom = 50 securityButton.layer.masksToBounds = true }()` and it pretty much works but I get the warning `'imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration` how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`imageEdgeInsets` is deprecated as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624034-imageedgeinsets

Here is the solution:

```
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
configuration.title = "Title"
configuration.subtitle = "Subtitle"
configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "swift")
configuration.titlePadding = 10
configuration.imagePadding = 10
configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 2,leading: 20, bottom: 2, trailing: 20)
```

**Buttons with title and image padding of 10, vertical padding of 2, and horizontal padding of 20.**

Use `UIButton.Configuration` as per your requirement.

Comment: contentInsets allows to move the title and the image at the same time, but I'd like to move the image and the text separately, any idea on how to do that? Do I have to remove the title from the button and create a label on top of it or I can move each of them separately?

Comment: @bigip You can tweak above to handle the insets of image and title as I am not sure about your design. however you can set empty subtitle or title to move the title but there is no direct way as we were using imageEdgeInsets as far as I researched.